# How to disable vim mouse wheel?

Tags: vim, archlinux, gnome-terminal

I want to know how to disable mouse wheel, however I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/610937/how-to-disable-scroll-wheel-in-vim) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44513/disabling-mouse-support-in-vim-in-a-gnome-terminal-environment) question and I have tried put them to my **.vimrc**:

```
set mouse=""

map <ScrollWheelUp> <nop>
map <S-ScrollWheelUp> <nop>
map <ScrollWheelDown> <nop>
map <S-ScrollWheelDown> <nop>
```

But none of them will disable the mouse wheel, I still can use it to scrolling.

And I'm on Arch Linux, using vim 7.4 with gnome-terminal 3.16.2.

Comment: In your terminal emulator turn off mouse reporting

Comment: @FDinoff Hmm...I've just seen the profile and I didn't find an option like that.

Comment: I don't have gnome-terminal on me right now. But the other thing you could try is adding the `map!` versions of the scroll wheel mappings to make sure you actually hit all modes. You currently miss insert mode and command mode.

Comment: @FDinoff Thanks, let me try it :)

Comment: Did you consider… not using it?

Comment: Oops, I've just leave for two hours and forgot this :P. I've just tried add something like `imap <S-ScrollWheelDown> <nop>` or `map! <S-ScrollWheelDown> <nop>`. And it's not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is probably a gnome-terminal problem and not a Vim one. With your .vimrc as it is, you can turn on and off the mouse wheel by issuing these commands in terminal

```
echo -e '\e[?1000h'
echo -e '\e[?1000l'
```

---

Edit: Previous answer doesn't work because gnome-terminal settings are
overridden by settings of Cinnamon (in this case), and maybe also because the
scrolling was done using a touchpad and not a mouse. It is possible to disable
scrolling with help of Synclient (command line utility to configure and query
Synaptics driver settings) putting

```
augroup scroll
    au!
    au  VimEnter * :silent !synclient VertEdgeScroll=0
    au  VimLeave * :silent !synclient VertEdgeScroll=1
augroup END
```

in your .vimrc.

This solution is not optimal for disabling scrolling even outside of Vim for as
long as Vim runs.

Comment: Hmm...`echo -e '\e[?1000h'` really disabled gnome-terminal mouse wheel. But first: when I try to scrolling, it will auto enter something like ``aE*`` or ``'B&'``. And I also can't click the terminal or select the text. And then, in vim it turned off the mouse wheel and wouldn't print these tings, but the *screen will scrolling*, I don't know how to explain this but however, it's not working.

Comment: Wow, so... I don't know. You can also try to ask on https://bbs.archlinux.org/. Sorry it didn't help.

Comment: No problem, actually I didn't know there is a way that can use command disable mouse wheel before :P

Comment: O.k., at least something new :)

Comment: Try to `set mouse=c`.

Comment: Interesting things: It's disabled my mouse(actually I'm using touch pad) wheel scroll for my Chrome, menu, etc. But I still can use it for vim and gnome-terminal. But if I disable my touchpad wheel in the system setting center(I'm using Cinnamon Desktop) it will works. So I have to disable the scroll in the setting center, not in the vimrc? :)

Comment: Yeah, it seems so :) Now just to figure out a method to automate disabling mouse wheel while you are working in Vim, and enabling it again while not.

Comment: Maybe I need find how does that work :). And thanks, I'll accept your answer, but I think this answer could be better :P

Comment: What about this one: `synclient VertEdgeScroll=0` (command in terminal)? Does it disable scrolling on the edge of touchpad in Vim?

Comment: Yes it does, seems like what does the setting in system setting center do.   And now I have an idea, I can create an alias like run this command when I start vim, and run `synclient VertEdgeScroll=1` when vim exit :)

Comment: Yes, that is it. I edit my answer, maybe we can try vim-style solution :)

Comment: Great, that is. Thank you so much!

Comment: Your welcome! it was really nice collaboration:-) Now I am too tired but I will try to make my answer to look better later.

Answer (score 4):

Dell XPS and Ubuntu 16.04 makes using the scrollwheel with vim an unbearable experience where I can't type anything because my hand makes the cursor move every few characters!!

Add this to `.vimrc` to completely disable mouse scrolling:

```
set mouse=a

nmap <ScrollWheelUp> <nop>
nmap <S-ScrollWheelUp> <nop>
nmap <C-ScrollWheelUp> <nop>
nmap <ScrollWheelDown> <nop>
nmap <S-ScrollWheelDown> <nop>
nmap <C-ScrollWheelDown> <nop>
nmap <ScrollWheelLeft> <nop>
nmap <S-ScrollWheelLeft> <nop>
nmap <C-ScrollWheelLeft> <nop>
nmap <ScrollWheelRight> <nop>
nmap <S-ScrollWheelRight> <nop>
nmap <C-ScrollWheelRight> <nop>

imap <ScrollWheelUp> <nop>
imap <S-ScrollWheelUp> <nop>
imap <C-ScrollWheelUp> <nop>
imap <ScrollWheelDown> <nop>
imap <S-ScrollWheelDown> <nop>
imap <C-ScrollWheelDown> <nop>
imap <ScrollWheelLeft> <nop>
imap <S-ScrollWheelLeft> <nop>
imap <C-ScrollWheelLeft> <nop>
imap <ScrollWheelRight> <nop>
imap <S-ScrollWheelRight> <nop>
imap <C-ScrollWheelRight> <nop>

vmap <ScrollWheelUp> <nop>
vmap <S-ScrollWheelUp> <nop>
vmap <C-ScrollWheelUp> <nop>
vmap <ScrollWheelDown> <nop>
vmap <S-ScrollWheelDown> <nop>
vmap <C-ScrollWheelDown> <nop>
vmap <ScrollWheelLeft> <nop>
vmap <S-ScrollWheelLeft> <nop>
vmap <C-ScrollWheelLeft> <nop>
vmap <ScrollWheelRight> <nop>
vmap <S-ScrollWheelRight> <nop>
vmap <C-ScrollWheelRight> <nop>
```

You will no longer be able to copy selections using Ctrl+Shift+C using the Terminal's bindings, so you'll have to use `"+y` within vim to copy your selection into the system clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .vimrc to disable the mouse wheel in vim.

source: https://github.com/mintty/mintty/issues/170

```
" disable mouse wheel
let &t_ti.="\e[?7786l"
let &t_te.="\e[?7786h"
```